# Map() function giving error in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to the spark programming. I have come across a scenario, to map each element of an RDD to another format. So I tried to get the 2nd element of the tuple(x._2). But it is giving an error Value _2 is not a member of Array[String]

[image: Spark map() error]

Do I miss something here... 
Pls helppp....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is its not tuple as you expect. Its an `Array[Array[String]]`. You can get the second element of an array with `array(1)`

```
month1.map(x => x(1))
```